# How to import underscore in angular2 using cli

Tags: angular

I have added file in angular-cli.json like below

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"
  ]
```

How can I import this file in my component

```
 import * as _ from 'underscore'; // How to implement this
```

Getting below error..

```
 ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Acadgild/frontend-
 advance/assignements/03:04:2017/custompipe/src/app/search.pipe.ts 
 (2,20): Cannot find module 'underscore'.
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm i -S lodash` on the command line

Then do `import * as _ from 'lodash'` in your ts files to import it